# How to Implement indexOf function of Java in Data weave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Hi i have a java function like

```
String firstName = appraiserName.substring(0, index);
String lastName = appraiserName.substring(index,stringLength);
```

In Dataweave i am trying it like below , why i am not getting the correct value. My expectation is to get the value as Vinoy

```
var participantResult = [
{
"participantFirstName": "ParticipantVinoy",
"participantLastName" :"Vinoy VKP"
}
]
fun getIndexLastName(lastname) =
if(null != lastname and sizeOf(lastname find " ") > 0 )
lastname[0 to (sizeOf(lastname find " "))]
else
null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the substringBefore() and substringAfter() functions of the Strings module. It will be easier.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-strings-functions-substringafter

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-strings-functions-substringbefore

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Ale's response you could use substring before and after or you could splitBy on " " and pick the first element of the resultant array.

For .e.g. in your case:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var participantResult = [
{
"participantFirstName": "ParticipantVinoy",
"participantLastName" :"Vinoy VKP"
}
]
fun getIndexLastName(lastname) =
if(null != lastname and sizeOf(lastname find " ") > 0 )
lastname[0 to (sizeOf(lastname find " "))]
else
null
---
//sizeOf(participantResult[0].participantLastName find " ") // result would be 1 and and thus your function would return Vi

//Try using substring before and after or splitBy - you can use this in your function

(participantResult[0].participantLastName splitBy(" "))[0]
```

Output:

```
"Vinoy"
```